# Get Prettier Traceback on Failure

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

Is there a way to receive more visually pleasing **traceback** message in Python 3 (I'm using the command line)? At the very least, I would like each call to be separated by a blank line.

Comment: What's wrong with the default traceback and how do you envision it being _prettier_?

Comment: @zwer I just want the lines to be separated a little bit, that's all I need. Nothing about the content of the message.

Comment: Nice question with nice comment to use `traceback` module to separate function calls in Traceback message with `\n`. `traceback` is really a nice module that allows us to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always define your own default exception handler through [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) and decide how to print the tracebacks. For example, if you just want an extra new line between the traceback lines, all you need to do is:

```
import sys
import traceback

def custom_traceback(exc, val, tb):
    print("\n".join(traceback.format_exception(exc, val, tb)), file=sys.stderr)

sys.excepthook = custom_traceback
```

Then if you do something like:

```
>>> 1/0
```

You'll get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Instead of the usual tidy output with a single new line between the entries. Of course, you can modify the `custom_traceback` to print your data however you want, just make sure you execute it early in your code - before you set the exception hook it will use the default traceback printing.

Answer (score 0):

**@Khoa Võ Đăng**, first of all, I appreciate your question. Python's traceback module is a correct choice (as **@zwer** has also suggested in comment).

> Python's traceback documentation link: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/traceback.html

I have presented 2 code smaples here.

- The first one shows the Python's default traceback (you are already familiar with this and don't want this traceback).
- The second one shows the custom traceback with 2 pictures attached. The first picture shows the output with `\n` as separator & the second picture shows `---------------------------` as separator.

> **Try online** »
>
> With `\n` as separtor (this is what you want) - http://rextester.com/QHIPTT48766
>
> With `--------------` string as separator (I added this to test) - http://rextester.com/GVVK50237

#### » Example 1 - Default Traceback

```
def func3(a):
    a/0;

def func2(a, b):
    func3(a);

def func1(a, b, c):
    func2(a, b);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1(12, 0, 89)
```

[image]

#### » Example 2 - Custom Traceback using traceback module

```
import sys, traceback

def func3(a):
    a/0;

def func2(a, b):
    func3(a);

def func1(a, b, c):
    func2(a, b);

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        func1(12, 0, 89)
    except:
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()

        # exc_type below is ignored on 3.5 and later
        exception_messages = traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                          exc_traceback)

        for exception_message in exception_messages:
            print(exception_message)
```

[image]

Changing the for loop in above code as follows:

```
for exception_message in exception_messages:
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print(exception_message)
```

[image]